# How to reset AJAX results input field

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, reset

I have a very lengthy form with multiple steps.  User needs to be able to click Reset in case they need to start over fresh.

I've implemented a very basic javascript like the one below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function resetOnlyThese(){
  document.getElementById('room_str').selectedIndex = "";
  document.getElementById('qty_str').selectedIndex = "";
  // ...
  }
</script> 

<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetOnlyThese()">
```

and I am using AJAX to update the form with calculations for price which displays in a SPAN.

```
<span class="totalprice-placeholder"></span>
```

All of the radios, input fields, and dropdown boxes reset perfectly but the price calculation generated from the successful AJAX callback remains the same.  Is there a way to reset the callback part too?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this script which loops through all the elements and resets them all very simply.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clear_form_elements(ele) {
    $(ele).find(':input').each(function() {
        switch(this.type) {
            case 'password':
            case 'select-multiple':
            case 'select-one':
            case 'text':
            case 'textarea':
                $(this).val('');
                break;
            case 'checkbox':
            case 'radio':
                this.checked = false;
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a clean-up function to the calculated fields.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function resetOnlyThese(){
    document.getElementById('room_str').selectedIndex = "";
    document.getElementById('qty_str').selectedIndex = "";
    // ...
    // add some clean up code to clear the span elements
    document.getElementById('totalprice-placeholder').innerHtml = "";
  }
</script> 

<!-- when referencing a specific html element it's better to use "id"
     instead of "class"
 -->
<span id="totalprice-placeholder"></span>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working though it makes sense.  Is it because that span doesn't have an ID?  is there a way to do getElementByClass or do I just assign an ID?

Comment: Sorry! You are right: I saw `class`, but *read* `id`... if you can, it's advisable to change class to id in context like these, because it yields better performance. I'll edit my suggestion to reflect it.

Comment: This is very odd.  Nothing I'm doing is working.  I changed from class to id... id to class.  checked spelling.  Ajax is updating this class upon user interaction with dropdown menus (which changes a price total).  Then if you click Reset, all fields go blank (like it should) but this total box remains still.

Comment: Cleaning the contents of `span` elements is not directly related AJAX -- it's just about DOM manipulation and javascript -- but there can be some *race* conditions that would fill these elements **after** they are cleaned. Can you post more information here or at [http://jsfiddle.net/]?